# add sum of multiple drop down list

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add the sum of my drop down list values to give a total value at the bottom...

this is my javascript:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$("#overtimehours").change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $.each($(".overtimehours") ,function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#sum").val(total)
});
    </script>
```

heres my php:

```
print "<td><div align=\"center\"><select name=\"overtimehours["; echo $transnum; print "]\"><option value=\"$ot_hours\">$ot_hours</option>"; overtimehours_list(); 
print "</select></div></td>\n";

print "<td><div align=\"center\"><b><input id=\"sum\" type=\"text\"/></b></td></tr>\n"; //add up OT hrs
```

**RESOLVED** :: HERES THE JSFIDDLE DEMO FIX: http://jsfiddle.net/st8Y3/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your PHP the same and do this...

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name="overtimehours"]', function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('select[name="overtimehours"]').each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sum').val(total)
});
```

---

EDIT:

PHP:

```
print "<td><div align=\"center\"><select class=\"overtimehours\" name=\"overtimehours["; echo $transnum; print "]\"><option value=\"$ot_hours\">$ot_hours</option>"; overtimehours_list(); 
print "</select></div></td>\n";

print "<td><div align=\"center\"><b><input id=\"sum\" type=\"text\"/></b></td></tr>\n"; //add up OT hrs
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).on('change', '.overtimehours', function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.overtimehours').each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sum').val(total)
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/st8Y3/3/

Comment: still not working... is it because my overtimehours is an array? .. i tried changing it to: 'select[name="overtimehours[$transnum]"]'  but still doesnt work.. grr

Comment: no errors. this is frustrating.. such a simple function i need yet nothing works lol

Comment: Can you remove this in your php file? ["; echo $transnum; print "]

Comment: no, i need that for each line.. i made a jsfiddle... here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/st8Y3/1/

Comment: All ID's **MUST** be unique.  I have edited my post.  Please refer to it.

Comment: great! works, but one small problem.. now it has problems adding decimal integers properly... 1.5 + 0.5 = 1 its showing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24332/discussion-between-rubberchicken-and-dom)

Comment: @rubberchicken That is because you are using `parseInt()` on the value. `1.5` will parse to `1` and `0.5` will parse to `0`.  Thus `1 + 0 = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You refer to `overtimehours` as both an id and a class name, yet your input has neither the id or class name.  I would suggest add a class called `overtimehours` to each input that is to be calculated and the change your selector to `$('.overtimehours')` instead of `$('#overtimehours')`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the class `overtimeshours` to your select declaration.

```
print "<td><div align=\"center\"><select class=\"overtimehours\" name=\"overtimehours["; echo $transnum; print "]\"><option value=\"$ot_hours\">$ot_hours</option>"; overtimehours_list();
```

Change your jQuery to:

```
$(".overtimehours").change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $.each($(".overtimehours") ,function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#sum").val(total)
});
```

More on [Class Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: Add the output of your html..not your php that's creating it..to the question. Or create a jsFiddle with the problem.